# Não consigo deletar os dados de uma entidade

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Tenho um método que deleta uma entidade Empresa e seus anexos, após o arquivamento de um protocolo, entretanto, quando tento deletar, acontece isso:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Entrada em lote 0 delete from pessoa where codigo='34635PI' foi abortada. Chame getNextException para ver a causa.
```

**Método para excluir a empresa e seus arquivos anexados**

```
public static void excluirEmpresaAposArquivamentoProtocolo(ArquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresaDao arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresaDao, EmpresaDao empresaDao, String codigoEmpresa) {
    Empresa empresa = empresaDao.pesquisarPorId(codigoEmpresa);
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String queryArquivosRegistro = "SELECT aroe FROM ArquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa aroe "
            + "WHERE aroe.empresa = :empresa";
    params.put("empresa", empresa);

    List<ArquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa> arquivosRegistroOnlineEmpresa = arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresaDao.listPesqParam(queryArquivosRegistro, params);

    for(ArquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresa aroe : arquivosRegistroOnlineEmpresa) {
        File f = new File(aroe.getCaminhoArquivo());
        f.delete();
        arquivoRegistroOnlineEmpresaDao.excluir(aroe);
    }

    empresaDao.excluir(empresa);
}
```

**StackTrace**

[Link para o Stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/wCQznvwg)

Comment: UserJ, por gentileza, edite poste a stacktrace do erro.

Comment: Coloquei no pastebin, o link está na pergunta

Comment: Nao posso acessar esse link, portanto não tem como ajuda-lo.

Comment: Dê uma lida em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Optei por colocar no pastebin, por causa da limitação de caracteres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado no stack trace do erro me parece que em algum momento você está tentando excluir uma `pessoa` sendo que ela ainda é referenciada por um `protocolo`.

Observe a linha a seguir do seu stack trace:

```
Grave: 143318 [http-thread-pool-8080(4)] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: update or delete on table "pessoa" violates foreign key constraint "fk53b964b79c58666b" on table "protocolo"
  Detalhe: Key (codigo)=(0000034635TPPI) is still referenced from table "protocolo".
```

Basicamente existe uma foreign key da tabela `protocolo` para a tabela `pessoa` e portanto você não pode excluir a `pessoa`.

Se seu objetivo é realmente deletar a `pessoa` sugiro que você remova primeiro a entidade `protocolo`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigada!